# Python, Pyplot - How to move two plots at the same time?

Tags: python, matplotlib, signals, move

I have two separate plots made by `pyplot` using code like this:

```
img=imread(name)
        g=figure(1)
        imshow(img)
        g.show()
```

These plots are two different images of the same object.

I need a way to redraw the second plot when I move or change the scale of the first one.

I know how to calculate the position in the other coordinate system and how to set plot limits but I have no idea how to force the second image to refresh when I move around the first one.

Comment: There are call-back events for draw events that you can use to trigger the draw of the other canvas.

Comment: Please answer your own question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out with:

```
def onclick(self):
    ...
    g.canvas.draw()
refresh=f.canvas.mpl_connect('button_release_event', onclick)
```

where:

```
img=imread(name)
f=figure(1)
imshow(img)
f.show()

img2=imread(name)
g=figure(2)
imshow(img2)
g.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

`g.canvas.draw()` should refresh the image drawn in `g`. See [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.draw) for more info.

Comment: Thanks. This will work but I need a way to trigger it when I move around the first plot.